# A simple way to do inheritance in rails with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

In Rails 4.2 I need some kind of inheritance for this structure:

- `User` has many `Reports`, `Report` belongs to `User`
- `ImpactReport` is a `Report`
- `ChallengeReport` is a `Report`
- `PlanningReport` is a `Report`
- `StImpactReport` is an `ImpactReport`

I've read about single-table inheritance supported by Rails, but I don't think it would let me go two levels deep on inheritance, also `StImpactReport` has a bunch of fields that are not in `ImpactReport`

I've also seen a lot of articles about how to implement muti-table inheritance, but they all seem quite complex, when in my head there's a much simpler way to do it.

I think it could be done simply with the `belongs_to` relationship in conjunction with `delegate` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` like this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ImpactReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report
  delegate :user, to: :report
  delegate :other_report_field, to: :report
end
```

and so on...

The advantages of this are:

- I have separate tables for each model, but only the fields specific to that model are in their tables, common fields are in the table of the parent.
- I can go as many levels deep as I like
- I can have, say, an `impact_report` and a `challenge_report` that both share the same `report` attributes. When the attribute is changed in one the other is also changed. (this is good for my app)

Disadvantages:

- It doesn't use class inheritance so methods of parents are not accessible to the children

My questions are these:

1. Are there any other disadvantages to this way of doing inheritance that I haven't thought of? Will it limit my application in some unforeseen way?
2. If I have a `report` object, what is the best way for me to access all the attributes of the children of this object?
3. If doing this structure, would it be better to use `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`?

Comment: Why not use class inheritance in this case and separate multiple tables?

Comment: @arogachev because when you use class inheritance with `ActiveRecord` classes it starts looking for a `type` column, which is not used in what I have described.

Comment: What's the related error? I used class inheritance without STI, and it was OK. Maybe you have column named `type`? So rename it to prevent conflicts because it's kind of reserved column name in Rails for STI.

Comment: @arogachev no error. I haven't implemented this yet. I just asked the 3 questions at the bottom of the post because I'd rather find out now if this is the wrong way to go instead of after spending ages implementing it. I'm going to do it the way I have described unless someone can tell me why it wont work.